# Closed-loop function question

Tags: system

How do I find the [image]

How do I find the transfer function of Gd(s)?

I am able to find the transfer function of Gr(s) but I am not really sure about Gd(s)? and how do i determine which order is this closed system?

Answer (score 1):

1. Find E(s) in terms of input - output
2. Find X(s) from E(s) i.e. multiply E(s) by the left hand block
3. Add D(s) to X(s) to get F(s)
4. Output is F(s) x the right hand block

Now you have a formula that contains the output on both sides: -

[image]

So do some algebra to reconcile the output to being on the left hand side of the formula (no other instances on the right hand side).

Now you have your output in terms of the input and D(s)

Because input and D(s) are independant you can create two more formulas that describe what you want with the unwanted input variable set to zero.

Comment: KL DC, if you are familiar with the classical formula for a transfer function with feedback (involving loop gain) it is very easy to find the desired transfer function. You can write down the equation without any math.